# CountDown check Time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, timer, count, countdown

I've made an countdown and i want to add an time check for it now. If the minutes are < 01 and the seconds are != 60 so 00:59 the Time should be orange and if the seconds are then smaller then 10 the time should be red.

But it does not work. 
They're always just getting orange if the time is 00:00:58, but why?

```
private int hours, minutes, seconds;
private bool paused; 

private void button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    button_Pause.Enabled = true;
    button_Stop.Enabled = true;

    if(paused != true)
    {
        hours = int.Parse(textBox_Hours.Text);
        minutes = int.Parse(textBox_Minutes.Text);
        seconds = int.Parse(textBox_Seconds.Text) + 1;
        textBox_Hours.Enabled = false;
        textBox_Minutes.Enabled = false;
        textBox_Seconds.Enabled = false;
        button_Start.Enabled = false;
        timer_CountDown.Start();

    }
}


private void timer_CountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(hours == 0 && minutes < 1)
    {
        label_Hours.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label_Minutes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label_Seconds.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }

    if(hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
    {
        timer_CountDown.Stop();
        textBox_Seconds.Enabled = true;
        textBox_Minutes.Enabled = true;
        textBox_Hours.Enabled = true;
        button_Start.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (seconds < 1)
        {
            seconds = 59;
            if (minutes < 1)
            {
                minutes = 59;
                if (hours != 0)
                {
                    hours -= 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                minutes -= 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            seconds -= 1;
        }

        if(hours > 9)
        {
            label_Hours.Text = hours.ToString();
        }
        else { label_Hours.Text = "0" + hours.ToString(); }

        if(minutes > 9) 
        {
            label_Minutes.Text = minutes.ToString();
        }
        else { label_Minutes.Text = "0" + minutes.ToString(); }

        if(seconds > 9)
        {
            label_Seconds.Text = seconds.ToString();
        }
        else { label_Seconds.Text = "0" + seconds.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

The Timer Intervall is 1000.

Comment: Look at the `PadLeft()` function, or, better yet, numeric format strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over complicating things. Why not just use the `TimeSpan` type and get rid of those `hours, minutes, seconds`?

```
private TimeSpan countDownTime = TimeSpan.Zero;

private void timer_CountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(countDownTime == TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        timer_CountDown.Stop();
        textBox_Seconds.Enabled = true;
        textBox_Minutes.Enabled = true;
        textBox_Hours.Enabled = true;
        button_Start.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }

    countDownTime = countDownTime.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Negate());

    label_Hours.Text = countDownTime.ToString("hh");
    label_Minutes.Text = countDownTime.ToString("mm");
    label_Seconds.Text = countDownTime.ToString("ss");

    if(countDownTime.TotalSeconds < 10)
    {
        label_Hours.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label_Minutes.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label_Seconds.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label10.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else if (countDownTime.TotalMinutes < 1)
    {
        label_Hours.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        label_Minutes.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        label_Seconds.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        label8.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
        label10.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
    }
}

private void button_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button_Pause.Enabled = true;
    button_Stop.Enabled = true;

    if(paused != true)
    {
        int hours = int.Parse(textBox_Hours.Text);
        int minutes = int.Parse(textBox_Minutes.Text);
        int seconds = int.Parse(textBox_Seconds.Text) + 1;

        this.countDownTime = new TimeSpan(hours,minutes,seconds);         

        textBox_Hours.Enabled = false;
        textBox_Minutes.Enabled = false;
        textBox_Seconds.Enabled = false;
        button_Start.Enabled = false;
        timer_CountDown.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is ts ? I just want to change the Colour of the Labels if the minutes are < then 1 to Orange and if the minutes are < then 10 then they labels should change the color to Red.

Comment: Do you mean If minute less than 1 to Orange and seconds less than 10 to red?

Comment: Updated my answer, check if that helps

Comment: Thanks, it workeed. Do you also know how i could let a label blink if the seconds are < then 5 ?

Comment: Just add another if block with appropriate condition and then toggle the label's visiblity to true and then false and so forth, which will give a impression that it is blinking. Feel free to ask another question in case any help required

Comment: Yeah, i did that but it didn't work. But now it is. I've forgot that if i do it with else if that just one block is executed. Thanks for your help. ;)